# ElasticSearch How can I filter one index by another and then agregate?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two index
First: customer `{userId:"",  mail:""}`
Second: reports`{id:"", userId:"",....}`

Need find: select from reports where userId not in customer and quantity(reports by userId)>10

Answer (score 1):

There are no joins in elastic search, it is not a relational database.

You need to denormalize your data, to improve the response time of a query at the expense of adding redundant data. Combine your models in a single index.

You can explore

1. [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html)
2. [Parent/Child Documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-query.html)

You should store reports data inside customer index.
Some articles on relationship in elastic search

1. https://blog.mimacom.com/parent-child-elasticsearch/
2. https://qbox.io/blog/parent-child-relationships-in-elasticsearch

Comment: I do this in two request 1) agregate by id and quantity >10 in index reports 2)then id from first request i filter by index customer. I didn`t find to make one request, that why I ask this question. Thanks!

Comment: @VSVDev I think it is better to club data together in a single model for faster response.